# Ansible truncate concatentated string

Tags: ansible

I am generating an yaml template in Ansible and I am trying to truncate two concatenated strings: 
Here the following code doesn't work because of the concatenation does not pipe into the regex_replace correctly.
I am only wanting the first n characters (first 10 characters in this example)

Normally I could just combine these two into one variable and then do

`{{variabel [:10] }}`

But I am no able to do that in this case because the file I am working in is getting combined with variables and then saved as a yaml file...

Basically I want to truncate the string without first combining or creating a new variable.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False


  vars:
    foo: "somelongstring"


  tasks:
- name: Display debug output
        debug:
          msg: "{{ foo  + '-moretext' | regex_replace('^.{0,10}', '\\1')  }} "
```

Answer (score 14):

To apply a filter or an operator on a complex expression (other than a sequence of filters), you have to surround it with parenthesis.

So to truncate the result of a concatenation in 1 action:

```
msg: "{{ (foo  + '-moretext')[:10] }} "
```

BTW, there is also the [`truncate` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#truncate):

```
msg: "{{ (foo  + '-moretext') | truncate(10, True, '') }} "
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.. I couldn't find the truncate filter on ansible docs but I did find this which will have a safe place in my bookmarks folder:
https://github.com/lxhunter/ansible-filter-plugins/blob/master/docs/jinja_functions.md

Comment: Most of the filters are jinja2 builtin filters: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#builtin-filters. Ansible added filters are documented here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html. The link you found is a good summary of all available filters.

Comment: The first solution works for me, however the `truncate` filter is not available in Ansible so the second solution is bad.

Comment: `truncate` is a Jinja2 builtin filter. It works perfectly in ansible: `ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ '0123456789' | truncate(4, True, '') }}"` ==> `0123`

Comment: @refriedjello: indeed, it doesn't seem to work if you don't specify the 4th parameter : `leeway` = "Strings that only exceed the length by the tolerance margin given in the fourth parameter will not be truncated...The default leeway on newer Jinja2 versions is 5 and was 0 before"
Example:
`ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ '01234' | truncate(4, True, '') }}"` ==> `01234`
whereas 
`ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ '01234' | truncate(4, True, '', 0) }}"` ==> `0123`