# Truncate string if greater than 15 charaters with Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I've a question. Maybe it's too simple but i'm newbie to Ansible.

I need to take the hostname of a machine and truncate it if its length is greater than 15 characters.

Is there a way to do that with an Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 4):

Certainly - Ansible scripts can directly use Jinja2 filters, of which `truncate` will do the trick. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107359/ansible-truncate-concatentated-string) and the Jinja2 [documentation on truncate](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#truncate)

```
{{ yourvariable | truncate(15, True, "") }}
```